# ReSorting users Ranking sorted by points

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table called "Ranking" which basically saves users ranking position sorted by their "points".
It's:

> *Id - Integer - A.I. (It's the position. 1 = first one. Highest points)
> *IdUser - Integer
> *PointsNow - Integer
> *PointsBefore - Integer
> *PositionBefore - Integer

What I'm trying to achieve is to have some method to know if an user went into a highest rank position or if he's lower now.

So for example, those are some entries:

> 1 | 2236 | 41 | 0 | 0
>
> 2 | 551 | 40 | 0 | 0
>
> 3 | 1557 | 34 | 0 | 0

So I though that I could achieve this doing this:

> *Delete all entries
>
> *Reset the autoincrement to 1
>
> *Copy PointsNow to PointsBefore and Id to PositionBefore.

I'm not sure if I should do it this way, or if there's a more logical option. I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a trigger to update PositionBefore, i.e. trigger before update PositionNow column, where to set PositionBefore column = PositionNow; and create a view to display the info as you need.

Comment: So, 'id' is a bit of a misnomer?

Comment: Don't store that kind of information. Just calculate it on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, u.idUser 
from User u, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
order by PointsNow desc;
```

If you just want to order the user based on the ranking:

```
SELECT * FROM User
ORDER BY PointsNow DESC;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
IdUser Integer primary key,
PointsNow Integer,
PointsBefore Integer,
PositionBefore  Integer);

INSERT INTO User(IdUser,PointsNow,PointsBefore,PositionBefore)
VALUES (2236,41,0,0),(551,40,0,0),(1557,34,0,0);
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76a26/2)

Important to note is that I have omitted the id column.  Use triggers to automate the query. See for more info on the ranking calculation. [MySQL update statement to store ranking positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196971/mysql-update-statement-to-store-ranking-positions).