# Updating user rank

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to update users' rankings in a single query but it crashes with this error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE users SET rank = @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY score DESC' at line 1

Is there anything wrong with my query?

```
SET @r=0;UPDATE users SET rank = @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY score DESC
```

I got the query from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197174/8139053)

I'm executing this query on a [node.js mysql library](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

```
    db.query('SET @r=0;UPDATE users SET rank = @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY score DESC', function(err){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Ranking updated successfully.");
    });
```

Comment: Where are you executing this statement? Directly in command line or in a programming language?

Comment: @Yannici updated question with code

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SET @r=0;UPDATE users SET rank = (@r+1) ORDER BY score DESC
```

I'm not sure as why you would want to reassign the var again.

Comment: Because he wants to have the new value in @r for the next user ;) (rank 1, rank 2, rank 3 ...)

Comment: Didn't work. I don't think it's about the query, it works without `SET @r=0;` but updates rank as NULL. I've updated the question with code.

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found the problem.

I forgot to set multipleStatements to true as described in [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries).