# Sql ranking query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a ranking query found from [MySQL update statement to list ranking positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196971/mysql-update-statement-to-store-ranking-positions) , but i have another requirement, after finding the rank i need to list ranking of my given player_id and few player above and below of the given player_id.

Is it possible to do it in a single query?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
rank player_id score
"1" "801"   "4995599"
"2" "800"   "4995599"
"3" "789"   "4995439"
"4" "1528"  "4993900"
"5" "1150"  "4993700"
"6" "2269"  "4993611"
"7" "465"   "4993523"
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:
player_id = 1528

```
rank player_id score
"2" "800"   "4995599"
"3" "789"   "4995439"
"4" "1528"  "4993900"
"5" "1150"  "4993700"
"6" "2269"  "4993611"
```

EDIT 1:
SAMPLE CODE:

```
SET @rank = 1, @seq = 1, @last = null;

select * from (
select *, @myRank := rank from (
SELECT *, @rank := if(@last = score, @rank, @seq) AS rank, @seq := @seq + 1, 
@last := score FROM score ORDER BY score DESC) as d where player_id = 789) 
as f where rank between @myRank -2 and @myRank + 2 ;
```

regards,
KUMAR KS.

Comment: Kindly add sample data along with desired output and your effort so far..

Answer (score 2):

do you mean this

```
SET @r=0;
select * from (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, p.* 
from player p,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by score desc) where rank>=@r-2 and rank<=@+2;
```

or this,I'm sure its performance can't be lower

```
    SET @play_id = 0;
    set @above=2;
    set @below=2
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                @rownum :=@rownum + 1 rank,
                p.*
            FROM
                player p,
                (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
            ORDER BY
                score DESC
    ) t
WHERE
    rank >=(select rank from (
        SELECT
            @rownum :=@rownum + 1 ‘rank’,
            p.*
        FROM
            player p,
            (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY
            score DESC
    ) a where play_id=@play_id) - @above
AND rank <=(select rank from (
        SELECT
            @rownum :=@rownum + 1 ‘rank’,
            p.*
        FROM
            player p,
            (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY
            score DESC
    ) a where play_id=@play_id) + @above;
```

Comment: similar to this where i will be giving my player_id, it should return two fields above and below my player_id

Comment: its giving errors, SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @KumarKS,sorry,i left out a table alias , answer updated

Comment: Its not even able query the 150,000 rows. My heidisql is crashing when i run this query.