# Update multiple row by one query but add 5 sec delay in modify_date column

Tags: sql, node.js, momentjs

I need to update multiple row by one query. I have created query as well and its working fine for me but now the issue is. I need to update modify_date with 5 second delay.

In my current user table I have 3 columns:

```
id | PID | name           | modify_date
1    1      employee      | 
2    1      employee      | 
3    1      employee      |
4    1      employee      |
```

My query:

```
Update name = 'Pritesh' 
where PID = 1
```

Above query is working for me. But I need to update `modify_date` column as well with 5 sec delay like for 1st row it will update 1 sec and for 2nd row it will update 5 sec like that.

Comment: How update without table name is working? Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: You could probably use RANK for that. Depends on the DBMS - mssql, oracle, mysql for sure  [mysql-update-statement-to-store-ranking-positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196971/mysql-update-statement-to-store-ranking-positions)